# Car Convoy Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, elementary-probability

Cars travel down a one-way single-track road. The nth driver would like to drive at speed $V_n$ , where $ V_1,V_2, ..., V_n$ are iid random variables. Cars will get bunched into convoys. If $V_2>V_1>V_3$ , then the first convoy will consists of cars 1 and 2 , and will be of length 2. Let L be the length of the first convoy. Find the probability $P(L=n)$ and the expectation $E(L)$.

Comment: I guess the intention was that the variables be iid and not just independent.

Comment: Yes of course!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: other questions with a similar set-up: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033468/expected-number-of-cluster-of-cars https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201807/probability-problem-cars-on-the-road https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151206/combinatoric-task-about-flock-of-sheep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- For the first convoy to be of length $L=k$, you need cars $2,3,\ldots,k$ to all be faster than car $1$, and car $k+1$ to be slower than car $1$
- As special cases, for the first convoy to be of length $L=1$ you need car $2$ to be slower than car $1$, and for the first convoy to be of length $L=n$ you need all the other cars $2,3,\ldots,n$ to be faster than car $1$

Comment: Nope.  For the first convoy to be of length L=k, you need car 2 is slower than car 1, car 3 be slower than car 2,... , car k-1 be slower than car k-2 and car k be faster at least one of cars 1,2,...,k-1. Convoy can't be of length L=1. Convoy to be of length L=2 you need car 2 be faster than car 1

Comment: @KouloubouDimitra If car 2 is slower than car 1 then the first convoy will definitely be of length 1, since car 2 will never reach car 1 and no other car will pass car 2

Comment: Thank you Very much!! Now I understand the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the distribution of speeds is continuous, so that the probability of two identical speeds is zero.

What matters is that the distribution of speeds is *iid*, therefore if you assign a *speed rank* to each driver (1 being the fastest, $n$ the slowest) all permutations of ranks have the same probability: $1/n!$.

(For example if $n=3$, the permutation [1,3,2] means that $V_1>V_3>V_2$).

Now, $L=n$ iff no car is slower than car #1, i.e. car #1 is the slowest. There are $(n-1)!$ permutations where this happens, therefore 
$$
P(L=n)={(n-1)!\over n!}={1\over n}.
$$

Comment: This calculates $P(L \geq n)$, not $P(L = n)$. So $P(L = n) = P(L \geq n) - P(L \geq n+1) = 1/n - 1/(n+1)$. It was obvious your answer could not be correct because $\sum_n P(L = n)$ must be $1$!