# Expected number of balls chosen from bag, I throw out everything in the bag with numbers less than the ball's

Tags: probability

I am mainly confused about my reasoning/solution

Problem: I have a bag of numbers ranging from $1,2... n$. I randomly choose a number and then I throw out all numbers less than that. Then I keep choosing numbers until I've found the largest one. What's the expected number of things I have chosen?

My Argument: I expect on average to have chosen a number of $n/2$ on each pick. Hence, everytime I choose a number, I expect to discard half of them. Hence, the $E(X) = \log_2(n)$

Note that I devised this problem as an equivalent one while trying to solve the "cluster of cars on one long road" question. If this is not equivalent, please let me know but I am confident that it is. As a result of this equivalency, I know my solution is incorrect. However, I cannot pinpoint where the issue arises.

[Probability problem: cars on the road](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201807/probability-problem-cars-on-the-road)

Comment: If $n=2$ then it takes one or two trials with equal probability, so $E[X_2]=\frac 32$.

Comment: @lulu Right, that's a good point, but I still don't understand what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: I really can't follow your argument.  It isn't true that I expect to throw out $\frac n2$ on the first turn...sticking with $n=2$ I expect to throw out $\frac 32$ on the first turn.

Comment: @lulu If you randomly draw a number, wouldn't you expect that number to be n/2? Hence, if you draw n/2, you throw out n/2 numbers.

Comment: Again, that argument does not work for $n=2$.

Comment: There's an easy recursion available...as $E[X_n]=1+\frac 1n \times \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}E[X_{n-1}]$.  Of course there may also be a simple closed formula, but at least the recursion let's you test lots of cases.

Comment: @lulu:  I derived that and put that into a spreadsheet.  It grows more slowly than $\log_2(n)$.  In particular, $E(32)\approx 4.058$ and $E(300)$ is only $6.28$

Comment: @RossMillikan  Yes, I agree with that value.  Are you citing that as a reason to doubt the recursion?

Comment: @lulu:  Not at all.  I am surprised that it grows so slowly.  It must be that you have a fair chance to come on a big number quickly, so throw away a lot of balls.

Comment: @RossMillikan  Right, I agree. It's not intuitive.   In fact, I simulated the process for a random level (I picked $26$ for some reason I can't recall), and it seems to work just fine.  Of course, my simulator follows the logic of the recursion (each choice gets you to the same operation with a lower cap) so perhaps I just re-coded a conceptual flaw.

Comment: @lulu That recursion gives $E[X_n]= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i = H_n$

Comment: @RossMillikan it is smaller than $\log_2(n)$ because  it is about $\log_e(n) + \gamma +\frac1{2n}$ with $\gamma \approx  0.5772$

Comment: @Henry  Ah, of course it does.  That's the problem with writing everything numerically...harder to spot obvious patterns.  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu: I found it quasi-numerically.  Multiplying the numbers by $n!$ gives a sequence of integers which turns out to be [OEIS A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254) and one of the formulae there is $n!\, H_n$ at which point it became clearer

Comment: Just to clarify, since this question has also been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483090) with the chosen number itself being returned, and the formulation here is slightly unclear: In this question, the chosen ball is removed from the bag, together with all lower ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others in the comments have computed the correct solution.  Here I will only comment on what I think went wrong with the "intuitive" solution of $\log_2 n$.

For slightly easier exposition, I change the game s.t. we throw out all numbers *larger* than the drawn number.  This way the numbers left are always $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$ and it is slightly easier (for me) to visualize.

Imagine $n=2^{10}=1024$ and I play the game $G$ as stated.  Meanwhile, you start with an identical bag and play a different game $G'$: at every step, you throw out exactly the larger half of all your remaining numbers.  So your game will take exactly $11$ steps to finish.  Which of us will finish first?

On your first draw, you draw $512$.  On my first draw, I have about $1/2$ chance to do worse than you (i.e. throw out fewer) by drawing $d > 512$ and about $1/2$ chance to do better by drawing $d < 512$.  However, when I do worse, I lost "less than a step" compared to your schedule, whereas when I do better, I can be gaining up to a step ($d \in [256, 511]$) or up to $2$ steps ($d \in [128, 255]$), or up to $3$ steps ($d \in [64, 127]$), etc. compared to your schedule.  Apologies if my boundaries above are not exactly correct, but hopefully you get the idea.  So intuitively, for large $n$ I should win easily.  This also means $E[X] < \log_2 n$.

Another way to look at it: Let $K_j$ be the largest remaining number (also number of remaining numbers) after $j$ steps, with $K_0 = n$.  For game $G'$, we have $\log_2 K_{j+1} - \log_2 K_j = -1$ exactly.  If it *were* true that for game $G$ we have $E[\log_2 K_{j+1} | K_j] - \log_2 K_j = -1$, then it is plausible that the answer would be $\log_2 n$.  However, in fact $E[\log_2 K_{j+1} | K_j] - \log_2 K_j < -1$.  For this reason $G$ finishes faster than $G'$.

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand your first argument. What do you mean by lag behind less than one step? Wouldn't you, by symmetry, lag behind by more than one step?

Comment: What I meant is: if I do worse, I would lag behind, but the amount by which I lag behind would be "less than one step".  (I would only lag behind by one step if I don't discard any numbers at all.)  Your steps are measured by $\log_2 K_j$, which decreases by $1$ every step.  If we measure my steps also by my $\log_2 K_j$, then it can decrease anywhere from almost $0$ to as high as $\log_2 K_j$ itself, and my average decrease is much more than $1$.

Comment: oh I see, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Here is the result of work in the comments by lulu, Henry, and me.

The expected number of balls is $E[n]=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1i=H_n\approx \log n + \gamma + \frac 1{2n}$, the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.

The recursion is $E[n]=1+\frac 1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}E[i]$ because you can imagine putting ball $n$ randomly into an arrangement of $n-1$ balls.  $i$ represents the number of balls before ball $n$.  You will then throw away $E[i]$ balls plus ball $n$.  We define $E[0]=0$ to make this come out properly when ball $n$ is put first in line.

We have $E[1]=1$ as the base case for strong induction.  Then if $E[j]=H_j$ for all $j$ from $1$ to $k$, 
$$\begin {align}E[k+1]&=1+\frac 1{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}H_i\\
&=1+\frac 1{k+1}\left(1+(1+\frac 12)+(1+\frac 12+\frac 13)+\ldots H_{k}\right)\\
&=1+\frac 1{k+1}\left(k+\frac{k-2}2+\frac{k-3}3+\ldots\frac{k-(k-1)}{k}\right)\\
&=1+H_k-\frac k{k+1}\\&=H_{k+1}\end {align}$$
To go from the second line to the third we count the number of terms $\frac 1m$ and note that it is $n-m$